# How to get data from the programs posted/deployed on Solana blockchain?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, solana, solana-web3js

I have been trying to get some data from Solana blockchain but always an error and I am not sure how to move forward.

I wrote a program, built it, deployed it and ran test cases using anchor. Now I want to use React/Nextjs for the front end and I am unable to fetch the data that I pushed on the Solana blockchain.

The program is deployed here: https://explorer.solana.com/address/ECj8sRDTpoGS7o71Tu9QC24sRsMWeqkzeJpxWozSbWxP?cluster=devnet

Here is my React code

```
const programID = new PublicKey(idl.metadata.address);
const { connection } = useConnection();
const program = await new Program(idl, programID, connection);
const xx = program.account.tweetOnSolana.all();
```

and I get following error

```
index.js?eee2:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProgramAccounts')
    at En.all (index.js?eee2:16:46435)
    at eval (useWalletHook.tsx?b0d5:37:46)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _callee$ (useWalletHook.tsx?b0d5:27:22)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?ecd4:45:16)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?ecd4:274:1)
    at prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?ecd4:97:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (_async_to_generator.mjs?7a98:3:1)
    at _next (_async_to_generator.mjs?7a98:25:1)
```

However when I run the following command, it works but it is encoded. I could see what I tweeted but its difficult to pull the data out of this buffer.

```
const tweets = await connection.getProgramAccounts(programID);

tweets.forEach((tweet, idx) => {
    console.log(tweet.account.data.toString());
});
```

[image]

There has to be a better way but seems like I can figure it out.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error:

```
index.js?eee2:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProgramAccounts')
```

It looks like your `connection` fetched using `const { connection } = useConnection();` isn't working.  Maybe check that code?

Otherwise, you can look at what `program.account.tweetOnSolana.all()` is doing to decode the accounts returned from `getProgramAccounts` and do the same thing.